# Is there a name for this dimensionless quantity?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, terminology, dimensional-analysis

I have an equation with the nondimensional number $\Delta P L / \sigma$.

Here $\Delta P$ is a characteristic pressure drop, $L$ is a characterictic length, and $\sigma$ is a characteristic surface tension. Is there a name for this number? I couldn't find it listed here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensionless_numbers_in_fluid_mechanics

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the book "Dimensionless Physical Quantities in Science and Engineering" it is known as the **Laplace Number**. In the book it is written both in the form you quote, and in the form listed in the Wiki-link you provided, where Laplace Number is also listed.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for the reference!

Answer (score 3):

As a follow on to Sparticle's answer, this is also known as a Suratman number (Su). From Wikipedia.